# M1. How can I move Storenames to another Website

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

M1. How can I move a storename to another website?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Steps

1. Rename old storename and add " OLD"
2. Create new storename under correct website
3. Open the storeview and link it to the newly created storename under 2
4. Delete the " OLD" storename from step 1
5. Reindex the whole lot

Be careful! If settings were stored on the " OLD" storename from step 1, then they will be lost. You can re-set them on the new storeview level.